# Creating model with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Now, I'm unable to change my db. (many millions rows in each table)

But I would like to create  my rails app though.

**My DB is absolutely not standard.**

Table name : `something_people`
Fields : `stid, stname, stfirstname, stage`

**I know to change the table_name:**

```
class People < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = "something_people"
end
```

I would like to rename too the fields. To use the symbol in my rails app and when I'll change the db structure, I only need to change the model classes.

```
class People < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = "something_people"
  self.field_name(:id) = "stid"
  self.field_name(:name) = "stname"
  self.field_name(:firstname) = "stfirstname"
  self.field_name(:age) = "stage"
end
```

an example of query :

```
@countid = People.where(hash_of_conds).count(:id)
```

is

```
SELECT COUNT(stid) FROM something_people WHERE myconditions;
```

**Asked question : How to do what I want to do ?**

If you don't understand, tell me.

Thank you.

Comment: What's the problem? I don't see any question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create aliases

```
class User < Activerecord::Base
  alias_attribute :id, :stid
  alias_attribute :name, :stname
end
```

But when you have a query like this

```
User.where("stname like '%ab%'")
```

you will have to specify the actual column name in the database

Comment: Thank you ! It works very well ! You didn't need a question to know my problem. I never did a `like` but maybe a `matches` will work.